# Some Integral Estimate

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration

I am currently trying to figure out the following estimate:

Let $\gamma: [0, 2 \pi] \to \mathbb C, \gamma(t) = e^{\mathrm i t}$, $\gamma^* := \gamma[0, 2 \pi]$ and $f: 
\gamma^* \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Then it holds
$$\left\vert \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz \right\vert \leq 4 \max_{z \in \gamma^*} \vert f(z) \vert.$$

Obviously the naive estimate yields 
$$\left\vert \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz \right\vert \leq 2 \pi \max_{z \in \gamma^*} \vert f(z) \vert.$$
So one needs to be a little bit more clever. So I wrote down
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{\mathrm i t}) \mathrm i e^{\mathrm i t} \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{\mathrm i t}) (\mathrm i \cos(t) + \sin(t)) \, dt
\end{align*}
Now I tried a few things. I tried to use $\vert z \vert^2 = \operatorname{Re}(z)^2 + \operatorname{Im}(z)^2$ and I wrote the integrals as double integrals achieving
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz \right\vert^2 &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(t - s) f(e^{\mathrm i t}) f(e^{\mathrm i s}) \, dt \, ds \\
&\leq \left( \max_{z \in \gamma^*} \vert f(z) \vert \right)^2  \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \vert \cos(t - s) \vert \, dt \, ds = 8 \pi \left( \max_{z \in \gamma^*} \vert f(z) \vert \right)^2
\end{align*}
by using the addition theorem, which is a better bound but not good enough. I guess one has to split the first integral in a clever way but I don't have any idea how. Maybe one can make some progress from using the connection between $\sin$ and $\cos$. It seems to be essential that $f$ has real values, but I don't see how to use it. I would appreciate some hints or solutions :)

Comment: Is that task a homework exercise? I would be quite amazed if such inequality is true.

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise.

Comment: It should be $\int_\gamma$ not  $\int_{\gamma*}$

Comment: Maybe, but $\gamma^*$ is the same if you reverse the orientation, while the contour integral changes sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to estimate $|\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)e^{it}\,dt|.$ This equals

$$e^{is}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)e^{it}\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(s+t)}f(t)\,dt$$

for some real $s.$  Now the above is nonnegative, so it equals

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\text { Re}\left (e^{i(s+t)}f(t)\right)\,dt. $$

Since $f$ is real valued (!), the last integral equals

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(s+t)f(t)\,dt \le M\int_0^{2\pi}|\cos(s+t)|\,dt. $$

Here $M$ is the maximum value of $|f|.$ We can take $s=0$ for simplicity in the last integral to see it equals $4.$ We're done.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your first equality. Nice solution though.

Comment: I don't see the mistake.

Comment: I edited your answer already.

Comment: Right, there was a typo there, thank you.